# Custom function in ng2-ckeditor

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor

I am working on Angular 4 project and using ng2-CkEditor in it. I have overridden the basic functionality of some buttons of the CkEditor like Save and Preview to execute my own function. Below is my code

```
<ckeditor  (ready)="OnReady()" [config]="editorConfig"  formControlName="EditorNote" #CkEditor>
                          <ckbutton
                            [name]="'customButton'"
                            [command]="'customCmd'"
                            [label]="'Click Me'"
                            [toolbar]="'CustomToolBar'"
                            [icon]="'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/5500999?v=2&s=16'">
                          </ckbutton>
                        </ckeditor>
```

I am overriding the buttons in the OnReady() method as follows --

```
public OnReady() {
    this.CkEditor.instance.addCommand("source", {
      exec: function() {
          alert("Custom handler for source button ");
      }
    });
    this.CkEditor.instance.addCommand("preview", {
      exec: function() {
           this.PreviewOfferLetter()
      }
    });
  }
```

The PreviewOfferLetter() method is as follows --

```
public PreviewOfferLetter() {
    const editorContentHtml = this.frmReviewOfferLetter.controls["EditorNote"].value;
    this._humanResourceService.PreviewCandidateOfferLetter(editorContentHtml).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {

      });
  }
```

Now when I am clicking the "Preview" button it throws an error in console which says --

```
this.PreviewOfferLetter is not a function
```

Please suggest if I am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're losing the context of your class with your syntax. Consider switching to fat arrows, which prevent that :

```
public OnReady() {
    this.CkEditor.instance.addCommand("source", {
      exec: () => {
          alert("Custom handler for source button ");
      }
    });
    this.CkEditor.instance.addCommand("preview", {
      exec: () => {
           this.PreviewOfferLetter()
      }
    });
  }
```

You can also use closures, which is uglier but also works :

```
public OnReady() {
    const self = this;
    this.CkEditor.instance.addCommand("source", {
      exec: function() {
          alert("Custom handler for source button ");
      }
    });
    this.CkEditor.instance.addCommand("preview", {
      exec: function() {
           self.PreviewOfferLetter()
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks dear, this really worked. Thank you so much :)